# Existence if integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How many integer solutions exist for:

\begin{cases}
  x+y=1-z \\
  x^3+y^3=1-z^2
\end{cases}

How do I do this. I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You should edit your post to include what you have tried. This will help the users of this site help you better.

Comment: I haven't done anything

Comment: Not doing anything is a problem. People like to see that you have put effort into attempting the problem yourself before they help you. Otherwise your question comes off as "*here's my homework, do it for me*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^3+y^3+z^2=1$$
$$x^3+y^3 + \underbrace{ (1-x-y)^2}_\mathrm{= 1-(x+y)^2} =1$$
$$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) + 1+ (x+y)^2 -2(x+y) =1$$
$$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) + (x+y) (x+y-2)=0$$
$$(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy+x+y-2)=0$$
Thus, if we have $x=k$ and $y=-k$ then we get $z=1$ and here we get infinite solutions $(x,y,z)=(k,-k,1)$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:$x^3+y^3 = (1-z)(1+z) = (x+y)(1+z) \to (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2-1-z) = 0 \to x+y= 0$ or $x^2-xy+y^2=1+z = 1+(1-x-y)$